# get all the form elements into an array

Tags: javascript

i have a form tag  and users can dynamically create the form by clicking on the elements they would want to be in that form . By clicking the elements get appended inside the form tag .

This is the function that is called .

```
function add_element(element)
{
    var startdiv = "<div class='form_content_middle_box' id = 'div"+i+"' onclick='javascript:edit(\""+element+"\",\""+i+"\");'> <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='javascript:remove("+i+");'>Delete</a></br>";
    var enddiv = "</div>";

    switch(element)
    {
        case 'textbox' :
            $('#myform_container').append(startdiv + "<label id='label"+i+"'>Untitled Textbox</label><p id='paragraph"+i+"'><input type = 'text' id='"+i+"'/></p>" + enddiv);
            form_elements.push(element);
            //alert(form_elements);
        break;
        case 'number' :
            $('#myform_container').append(startdiv + "<label id='label"+i+"'>Untitled Textbox</label><p id='paragraph"+i+"'><input type = 'number' id='"+i+"'/></p>" + enddiv);
            form_elements.push(element);            
        break;
        case 'textarea' :
            $('#myform_container').append(startdiv + "<label id='label"+i+"'>Untitled Textarea</label><p id='paragraph"+i+"'><textarea id='"+i+"'></textarea></p>" + enddiv);
            form_elements.push(element); 
           // alert(form_elements);
        break;
        case 'checkbox' :
            $('#myform_container').append(startdiv + "<label id='label"+i+"'>Untitled Checkbox</label><p id='paragraph"+i+"'><input type = 'checkbox' id='"+i+"' /></p>" + enddiv);
            form_elements.push(element);
        break;
        case 'radio' :
            $('#myform_container').append(startdiv + "<label id='label"+i+"'>Untitled MultipleChoice</label><p id='paragraph"+i+"'><input type = 'radio' id='"+i+"'/></p>" + enddiv);
            form_elements.push(element);
        break;
        case 'dropdown' :
            $('#myform_container').append(startdiv + "<label id='label"+i+"'>Untitled SelectBox</label><p id='paragraph"+i+"'><select id='"+i+"'><option></option></select></p>" + enddiv);
            form_elements.push(element);
        break;

        default:
        break;
    }

    i++;
}
```

After the form has been created , the user will click on save and i need to save that form ,
i want to know a way to get all the elements and the values that the user has appended.A way to save the form along with all the elements in an array or something

Comment: you might want to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454897/how-to-use-jquery-to-get-all-the-submitable-elements-in-a-form

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try

```
var myElements=$('#myformID').find('input, textarea, button, select')
```

The variable `myElement` will be cast to an array and will have all the elements in the form.

Iterating through the variable `myElements[index]` will give the form element and 
`myElements[index].value` will give the form elements value

Answer (score 0):

I see your java script function and I understand that you are using a form as well.
By doing this, your form's data will be passed to a servlet or restful web service

```
<form name="f" action="rest/myMethod" method="post">
    ... //your form contents
</form>
```

In your *myMethod* you can have all those information and store them in array/file/db ...

Comment: the above will only give the values of the form (if filled).i want to save the form to create the html of it later . So i want the elements in the form along with the values

Comment: You can have your JavaScript inputs be sent to your app too. All you need is to have some hidden form fields that will be filled by your JavaScript.